# Binding Json data to a scroll view

Tags: iphone

I am retrieving Json data from url. There is a lot of text in the url which is to be binded to the Scroll view. Can anyone plz suggest me how to do it. I have no problems in retrieving Json data . I have included a scroll view on the main view. I have to just bind the data to the pre defined scroll view...

Comment: Do you want to display the Json data in scroll view as plain text?

Comment: yes... i want to just display the json data as plain text

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean uitableview instead of scrollview.
To do it, just retrieve the data from webservice into a dictionary or an array and feed that data to tableview through uitableview datasource methods.

Comment: i want to just display the json data as plain text. not in a table view

Comment: then just use one of the JSON frameworks avaliable (like touchJSON or JSON-framework), they turn json into a dictionary - just extract the keys you need...